# How to move a sprite along a line a certain amount of pixels at a time?

Tags: java, javafx

If you have a sprite at position (100, 100) and want to move it along a line to position (200, 300), how do you do so in increments of say 5 pixels max. At the moment, I am simply using the difference in x/y position to calculate the length and move the sprite 1/10 of the length at a time.

Instead I want it to move by 5 pixels max. So for this example, as the next y position is 2x as far away than the next x position, it should be moving 2x further in the y direction such that the sprite arrives at the position via a straight line.

Current code:

```
public void move() {
    double currentX = this.getCenterX();
    double currentY = this.getCenterY();
    double nextX = next.getCenterX();
    double nextY = next.getCenterY();

    // Used to jump by 1/10 edge length
    double xDif = Math.abs(currentX - nextX);
    double yDif = Math.abs(currentY - nextY);

    // Move by 1/10 the length in correct direction
    if (currentX > nextX) {
        this.setX(this.getX() - (xDif/10));
    } else if (currentX < nextX) {
        this.setX(this.getX() + (xDif/10));
    }

    if (currentY > nextY) {
        this.setY(this.getY() - (yDif/10));
    } else if (currentY < nextY) {
        this.setY(this.getY() + (yDif/10));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the movement vector you first need to get the direction vector in order to get the direction's unit vector (a vector which is one in length).

The direction vector is the delta (difference) between your start and finish points `x1 - x0, y1 -y0`.

To get the unit vector, you take each vector component `(x, y)` and divide it by the vectors total magnitude `sqrt(x^2 + y^2)`.

```
double xDirection = currentX - nextX;
double yDirection = currentY - nextY;
double magnitude = Math.sqrt(xDirection*xDirection + yDirection*yDirection);

double xUnit = xDirection/magnitude;
double yUnit = yDirection/magnitude;
```

Now if you want to move only 5 pixels total, then you can make your movement vector by multiplying each component of the unit vector by 5:

```
double xMovement = xUnit * 5;
double yMovement = yUnit * 5;

this.setX(this.getX() + xMovement);
this.setY(this.getY() + yMovement);
```

Comment: That is spot on you legggggeenddd! I knew it was something to do with the magnitude (Pythagoras was in my head) and I tried a load of combinations to no avail. Hadn't realised the xDirection/magnitude part though. Thanks a lot, accepted answer +rep ;)

Comment: @ReadyPlayer2 vector math can be pretty tricky stuff. Don't be afraid to pick up a linear algebra textbook, they can save you lots of time down the road!

Comment: Luckily for what I'm doing this is as far as the vector math goes, but I'll be sure to do so if I ever do something more complicated! Thanks again!

Comment: [Here's an excellent book](http://natureofcode.com/book/chapter-1-vectors/) that handles vector math, moving sprites, etc.